# How to get comma separated item IDs from MultiSelectSpinner in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner, android-spinner, multi-select

I'm using this [MultiSelectSpinner](https://github.com/apptik/multiselectspinner) control from Github in my Kotlin project. I don't know how to get `Id` of a selected item from this control and I need to set that comma-separated IDs string of all selected items to `tv_engineer_ids` TextView control.

**Layout Code:**

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_engineer_ids"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <io.apptik.widget.multiselectspinner.MultiSelectSpinner
                android:id="@+id/spin_engineer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                />
```

**Kotlin Code:**

```
val engineers: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>();
    addJobResponse.engineerList!!.forEach {
        engineers.add(it.name!!);
    }

    spin_engineer.setItems(engineers)
            .setListener<BaseMultiSelectSpinner>(object: BaseMultiSelectSpinner.MultiSpinnerListener {
                override fun onItemsSelected(selected:BooleanArray) {
                    //Toast.makeText(context, selected.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
  // Need to set comma separated IDs here
                    selected.forEach {
                        Toast.makeText(context, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

                }
            })
```

`engineerList` is the list of `Engineer` data class.

**EngrList Data Class Code:**

```
data class Engineer (
    @SerializedName("Id")
    @Expose
    var id: Long? = null,
    @SerializedName("Name")
    @Expose
    var name: String? = null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of using a `forEach` and adding engineers to a new `ArrayList` one by one in the beginning, you could use [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html):

```
val engineers: List<String> = engineerList.map { it.name!! }
```

Then, inside the listener you can use [`filterIndexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-indexed.html) to get a list of the `Engineer`s that are on indexes where the `selected` array contains `true`:

```
val selectedEngineers: List<Engineer> = engineerList
        .filterIndexed { index, engineer -> selected[index] }
```

And finally, for a comma separated list, [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html):

```
println(selectedEngineers.joinToString { it.id!!.toString() })
```

Comment: Thanks, Haptic answer.